# Running a container executing a .jar on a raspberry pi

Tags: java, docker, raspberry-pi

I have an issue running a container which should execute a .jar file on a raspberry pi. The .jar contains a simple "Hello world" example code. I use Java 17, the raspberry pi runs on arm64v8.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM arm64v8/openjdk:17-jdk-slim

WORKDIR /
ADD helloworldtest.jar /helloworldtest.jar 

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/helloworldtest.jar"]
```

I tried cmd instead of `ENTRYPOINT` too but there was no change in the behavior.

My build command:

`docker build --platform linux/arm/v8 helloworldtest`

Then I tag/push the container and everything seems to be okay.

But if I try to run the docker on my raspberry pi there is no output and it seems like the docker couldn't be started properly (`Exit Code 159`) - there is no other error message.

Do I miss something here? What could be the issue?

Comment: One addition: If I run it on windows everything works fine but as soon as I run it on my raspberry pi there seems to be an issue.

Comment: You will need to show more details of the actual errors you are seeing - including the commands executed. Try running a simple container - `busybox` or something - so you can check if your basic docker is correct rather than a specific problem with your custom image.

Comment: A simple container like Hello-World works finde and runs as expected. However if I want to run my docker it's not working - or at least the .jar is not executed. 
Unfortunatly there is no error message except from the Exit (159) when I look at docker -ps -a. There are no other logs or error messages.

Comment: What is the docker command that you use to run the container? Because depending on how you run it, you may need to explicitly attach standard in and standard out using the `-i` and `-t` options to get any output on the console.

Comment: Your sample `Dockerfile` had the `WORKDIR` and `ADD` commands on the same line. Was that correct?

Comment: That's just a format issue, in my docker file it's two lines.

Comment: The command I run is simply "docker run repostirory/name:tag" I tried it with -i too but it still didn't work. My guess is that the jdk doesn't work correctly on arm64/v8...but I haven't found one that does until now.

Comment: You won't get any console output if you don't add `-i` and `-t`, which is probably the reason why you don't get any error message. To debug more, you can try to run bash in the container like so: `docker run -it repository/name:tag /bin/bash` This should give you a normal shell, but inside the container, allowing you to poke around and try things out.

Answer (score 1):

So you start a container by issuing something like

```
docker run repository/name:tag
```

but all you get is a display of `Exit (159) when I look at docker -ps -a` when running `docker ps -a`. Well, you should have a container id and a container name - something you can reference. Try to retrieve the logs by running

```
docker logs <container name or id>
```

I suspect that the `java` executable is not found. Provide it with full path as even the environment variable PATH may not be set within the container or shell interpretation is turned off because you use the entrypoint directly instead of running a shell first.